# node.js Transfer and saving files using TCP Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I have a lot of devices sending messages to a TCP Server written in node. The main task of the TCP server is to route some of that messages to redis in order to be processed by another app.

I've written a simple server that does the job quite well. The structure of the code is basically this (not the actual code, details hidden):

```js
const net = require("net");

net.createServer(socket => {
  socket.on("data", buffer => {
    const data = buffer.toString();
    if (shouldRouteMessage(data)) {
      redis.publish(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Most of the messages are like: `{"text":"message body"}`, or `{"lng":32.45,"lat":12.32}`. But sometimes I need to process a message like `{"audio":"...encoded audio..."}` that spans several "data" events.

What I need in this case is to save the encoded audio into a file and send to redis `{"audio":"path/to/audio-file.mp3"}` where the route is the file with the audio data received.

One simple option is to store the buffers until I detect the end of the message and then save all them to a file, but that means, among other things, that I must keep the file on memory before saving to disk.

I hope there are better options using streams and pipes. ¿Any suggestions? (some code examples, would be nice)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved, so I post the solution here for documentation purposes (and with some luck, to help others).

The solution was, indeed, quite simple: just open a write stream to a file and write the data packets as they are received. Something like this:

```
const net = require("net");
const fs = require("fs");

net.createServer(socket => {
  socket.on("data", buffer => {
    let file = null;
    let filePath = null;
    const data = buffer.toString();

    if (shouldRouteMessage(data)) {
      // just publish the message
      redis.publish(data);
    } else if (isAudioStart(data)) {
      // create a write stream to a file and write the first data packet
      filePath = buildFilePath(data);
      file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
      file.write(data);
    } else if (isLastFragment(data)) {
      // if is the last fragment, write it, close the file and publish the result
      file.write(data);
      file.close();
      redis.publish(filePath);
      file = filePath = null;
    } else if (isDataFragment(data)) {
      // just write (stream) it to file
      file.write(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Note: `shouldRouteMessage`, `buildFilePath`, `isDataFragment`, and `isLastFragment` are custom functions that depends on the kind of data.

In this way, the incoming data is *streamed* to the file directly and no need to save the contents in memory before. node's streams rocks!

As always the devil is in the details. Some checks are necesary to, for example, ensure there's always a file when you want to write it. Remember also to set the proper encoding when converting to string (for example: `buffer.toString('binary');` did the trick for me). Depending on your data format, the `shouldRouteMessage`, `isAudioStart`... and all this custom functions can be more or less complex.

Hope it helps.